# How can I reset my default home directory in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am taking a front-end dev course on udacity.com. I am currently learning Git and I am stuck.

I was working on a project and I thought I was following instructions and making a branch called 'include-andras-destinations'. Somehow, this branch is now part of my home directory, but I want to use a different directory to store my Git projects and inside the parentheses, it should be: (master), like in the attached pic.

Anyone knows how can I reset my default home directory/branch and get rid of "include-andras-destination"?

I would like udacity-git-course folder to be my master (is that right?)

If I type:

```
cd /Users/ruxandravasilescu/Desktop/udacity-git-course
```

I get:

```
ruxandravasilescu (include-andras-destinations) udacity-git-course
```

I don't understand why is that branch always present! Otherwise, git seems set-up okay. I work on a mac. Below is a little info from my terminal

```
ruxandravasilescu (include-andras-destinations) ~
$ cd
ruxandravasilescu (include-andras-destinations) ~
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/ruxandravasilescu/.git/
ruxandravasilescu (include-andras-destinations) ~
$ pwd
/Users/ruxandravasilescu
ruxandravasilescu (include-andras-destinations) ~
$ git status
On branch include-andras-destinations
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

Udacity's git setup on mac looks like this and that's how my terminal initially looked also:

[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend looking up the differences of directories and branches in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a git repo in your home directory. Just remove it and you should be fine:

```
$ rm -rf /Users/ruxandravasilescu/.git/
```

Answer (score 0):

With git branches they aren't really directories on your computer.. at somepoint did you type

```
 `git checkout (include-andras-destinations)`  ?
```

You may try git checkout master if that's the case to get back to your repo's main branch.

Comment: I did type git checkout master and I got an error, no such file

Comment: Were you in the main git directory when you typed that? If you're at the top of the directory there will be a .git file present

Comment: I think that's the problem, I wasn't, but i don't know where is my main git directory. Shouldn't that be the default directory for my repos?

Comment: Typically each git repo you have will have it's own directory. For example the current setup on my computer is E://Programming/Github/ and in that directory I have several different repos.

Comment: As a further example if I wanted to check out dev branch on 'dummy_dir_123' I would do -- cd E://Programming/Github/dummy_dir_123 and from within that directory I would type -- git checkout dev