# Git attempting to stage 5000+ documents

Tags: git, staging

I'm running into a problem with github on my computer. It started when I installed brew on my mac, I also used git init within a program folder today inorder to push it to my repo, but this is something I had done before. When I run `git status`, this is what I get:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
.DS_Store
.Trash/
.bash_history
.bash_sessions/
.cache/
.config/
.docker/
.eclipse/
.kube/
.oracle_jre_usage/
.ssh/
.subversion/
.tooling/
.vscode/
Applications/
Desktop/
Documents/
Downloads/
Library/
Movies/
Music/
Pictures/
Public/
eclipse-workspace/
git/
go/
google-cloud-sdk/
mydockerbuild/
mydockerbuild2/
```

For some reason, it's trying to push my entire PC through to github, which is making my VS code less and less functional (not opening up full documentation, etc.). It also had this for a couple other files that I used git clean -f on, but I don't want to delete any of these for obvious reasons. Please help!
Also I just started git so please cut me some slack if im not being explicit.

Comment: It seems you have run `git init` in the home directory. Remove the folder `.git` there. Run `rm -rf ~/.git` in git-bash.

Comment: Then I would guess that you've placed your `.git` folder at the root level of your disk drive.  Don't do that; init/clone a Git repo into the subfolder where you really want it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset my default home directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806510/how-can-i-reset-my-default-home-directory-in-git)

Comment: @ElpieKay was right, I had a folder in my home directory...thanks a lot guys