# Git attempting to stage 5000+ documents **on Windows**

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, git-stage

I have the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166441/git-attempting-to-stage-5000-documents) but I'm on Windows.
I searched everywhere to fint a `.git` (not only in `Windows`) but nothing. 
Not even in projects where I did `git init` (via the terminal of VS code). 
I suppose that's why I get this error. Because all the projects where I use git, use the same `.git` file that is somewhere...

When I run (in a project) `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to find out where my git repository root is, I get `C:/Users/username`. Which is of course wrong! But in there (as you see in pic) there is no `.git` file. Should I delete `gitconfig`?[image: Where is .git]

1. How can I find the `.git` that creates the problem?
2. Why my projects that I've used `git init` don't have a `.git` file?

[image: 5k changes]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel -> File Explorer Options

Select the "View" Tab

Select the following options:

- Check: Show Hidden files, folders and drives
- Uncheck: Hide extensions for known file types
- Check: Show drive letters
- Check: Show encrypted or compressed NTFS files in colour
- Check: Navigation Pane/ Expand to open folder
- Check: Navigation Pane/ Show all folders

You should now see the .git folder, and delete or rename it.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the file. Then i went back to my project and initialized again a git repository. I got a `.git` file in my project... all good. But I still get the 5k changes (see 2nd pic above).

Comment: @FotisTsakiris In VSCode, just open the folder you want not the Users/free-do folder. File->Open folder...   … Also it sounds like you have again initialised the git repository in the wrong place.

Comment: It's OK. I tried to to initialize a git repo in a **new** project and it works. Thanks a lot.